# Tap imageview to open image in Gallery on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, android-image

I'm making an app, that is displaying an image in a single activity.
Im using an json feed to get the url of the image, an it downloads the image via the lazyloader function, and then displays it in an ImageView
What I need to create is that when you tap the imageView, The image gets displayed in the standard android image gallery.

How do i make this happen? I've tried various things with intents but i can't get it to work...

Pleasse help me guys!

Thanks

Comment: Standard gallery means default gallery in Device?

Comment: Yes... The default gallery to view images

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to launch a viewer for the image. Uri is the file uri which you want to launch

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri); 
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do I obtain the File URI?